# How to dump path to source from object-file

Tags: c, gcc, objdump, object-files, nm

Assume I have a C object-file `app.o` compiled with gcc. How can I dump the file path to the original `app.c` from which `app.o` was compiled. My goal is to create a listing of all symbols + respective source file path using the binutils and gcc toolsuite.
By no means am I expecting an all-in-one solution. So I tried playing with multiple tools to gather the information I need.

Inspecting the object-file with a text-editor reveals that (appart from a lot of unreadable binary gibberish) the file *does* contain a reference to `app.c` as a string embedded into the object-file format. However I did not find a way to extract that string using `objdump` or `nm`.

I was hoping `objdump` would have some flag that could extract this source file string, but after trying virtually all options documented in the `man` page I still couldn't find it.

With the path of the source file I was hoping I could run `gcc -M <path-to-source>`. This would allow me to look through all the headers included by `app.c` and find the in-source declarations.

Suppose a simple `app.c` like this:

```c
void foo(void) {
}
```

Compile it via `gcc -c app.c -o app.o`.

Running `objdump -t app.o` dumps the symbol table, but does not refer anywhere to the original `app.c`.
Running `cat app.o` does show that the object-file contains the file path to `app.c` (relative to pwd at compile-time). But I wasn't exactly planning on writing my own object-file parser just to get to that string.

Comment: could dwarfdump help you?

Comment: I quickly looked into it, indeed `dwarfdump` might be usable for what I need. Only downside is that it requires the object file to be built with debug information (`gcc -g ...`), which isn't that big of a deal tbh. What I'm more worried about is availability on MinGW. I didn't mention it in the original post, but I would like to have it working on native Linux *and* MinGW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question minutes after posting it (duh!):

`readelf -s app.o` prints a symbol table including the name of the source file (`app.c`). With that I am able to run `gcc -M app.c` and then parse through all header files to gather the symbol declarations.